# Is $\ell_2(A)$ a Hilbert C$^*$-module with Opial property?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If $A=Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) $,   Is $\ell_2(A)$ a Hilbert $A$-module with Opial property?

Opial property: If ($w-\lim x_n=0   $) then $ 
 (\liminf \lVert x_n\rVert<\liminf \lVert x_n-y \rVert  $) for all $y\ne 0$.

I tried to solve it for many hours, But I didn't solve it.

Comment: Do you have a definition for this property ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opial_property

Comment: The answer is yes. Hint, think about why ordinary $l^2$ has this property. The two cases are very similar.

Comment: And waht is the Opial property for $A$ Hilbert modules ? Do we consider the topology associated to the $A$ linear continuous maps $\phi : M \to A$ for the weak topology?

Comment: The Opial property in the Hilbert A-module $\ell_2(A)$ is equivalent to  $ \liminf  \lVert \langle x_n,x_n\rangle \rVert < \liminf \lVert \langle x_n,x_n\rangle +\langle y,y \rangle \rVert $ for all $y\ne 0$.

Comment: In Hilbert spaces we use parallelogram property to show that a Hilbert space has Opial property . In the space $\ell^p$ we use uniformly convex property to show that they have Opial property.  But in the Hilbert $A$-module $\ell^2(A)$ we don't have parallelogram and uniformly-convex properties.

Comment: And $\ell_2(A)$  is not similar to $\ell^2(\mathbb{C})$. I don't know what I've to do? Should I prove it or give a counterexample?

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you have answered not my question. Because in the Hilbert module $\ell_2(A)$ the norm is defined by $\lVert .\rVert=\lVert \sum {a_j}^*a_j \rVert^{\frac{1}{2}}$.   And I knew today that  $\ell_2(A)$ doesn't have Opial property:   $$x_n=(0,0,\ldots , 0,\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix} , 0 ,\ldots ) $$ (number of 0 before the matrix is n, so $x_n \to 0(weakly)$) and   $$ y= (\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} , 0 , 0 , \ldots ) $$ So $\liminf \lVert x_n\rVert = \liminf \lVert x_n-y\rVert$.

Comment: Ah, I interpreted $l^2(A)$ differently.  But yes, this is the Hilbert module norm.